# Exposing .NET MVC Service layer as REST endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I have a .NET MVC application with a service layer that we inject using Unity into the controllers to separate view logic from business logic.  Is there any way to expose the same service layer methods as REST endpoints so that other applications could use our service layer as a REST API, while still using the service layer in our monolithic application?

Are there any examples of someone doing this?

Comment: I'd recommend using [ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) to create your REST API. It can use the same service layer as your .NET MVC app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you can create a separated project using ASP.Net Web Api.

Using Web Api, you should be able to inject your services into your controllers and call those Rest Services from your MVC application as well as from any other application (mobile, etc).

You can also consider, in case you are using EF, creating a separate project(layer) for your repository and inject the `EF Context` into your repositories, the repositories into your services layer and your services into your controllers.

In my personal projects, I call the services layer only from my WEB API project and never from my MVC application. The MVC will use the services layer only through your REST Services.

Comment: That's really the architecture I would like to move towards, but I can't find examples where people have implemented MVC in that manner.  Do you have a reference where you first saw that type of implementation?  I have been Googling my fingers off, but there are so SO many different ways of approaching the same problem in .NET

Comment: In pluralsight you can find a lot of examples:
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/
There's a lot of courses. Take a look at the authors' GitHub repositories, most of them have his sample codes on GitHub.